# Using with statements for two objects returns error in VBA Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access

I tried to refactor my codes by using with statements. The following code generates run-time error '438':

> Object doesn't support this property or method

starting at line 15. Why can't I use `With col1` within `With frm`?

```
01  Public Sub SetWellInputs()
02      Dim col1 As Collection
03      Dim i As Variant
04      
05      'Collection of two associated values
06      Set col1 = New Collection
07      Set frm = [Form_Groundwater Database]
08      With frm
09           'Wells Table
10          
11          strWellID = .Well_List.Column(0, .Well_List.ListIndex + 1)
12          strPermitID = .Permit_List.Column(0, .Permit_List.ListIndex + 1)
13          
14          With col1            
15              .Add Array(.Well_Name_Text.value, strWellName), "1"
16              .Add Array(.Well_Diameter_Text.value, strWellDiameter), "2"
17              .Add Array(.Well_Casing_Text.value, strWellCasing), "3"
18              .Add Array(.Screened_Interval_Text.value, strScreenedInterval), "4"
19              .Add Array(.Well_Sock_Check.value, strWellSock), "5"
20              .Add Array(.Well_Depth_Text.value, strWellDepth), "6"
21              .Add Array(.Well_Comments_Text.value, strWellComments), "7"
22              .Add Array(.Well_Active_Check.value, strWellActive), "8"
23          End With
24          For Each i In col1
25              If i(0) <> vbNullString Then
26                  i(1) = i(0)
27              End If
28          Next
29          
30      End With
31      
32  End Sub
```

Comment: I believe VBA assumes in line 15's `.Well_Name_Text.value` belongs to collection col1, but col1 doesn't have such a property or method. Try using `.Add Array(frm.Well_Name_Text.value, strWellName), "1"`

Comment: Think about it. With blocks are used to avoid needing to explicitly referencing an object. So, any dot reference is going to be applied to the current block. In your case col1. Anything within the frm block, but  before or after the col1 block will reference frm. Anything within the col1 block can only reference col1.

Answer (score 2):

With blocks can be nested, but the dot notation can only scope to the immediate `With`, as per the MSDN help:

> You can nest With statements by placing one With block within another. However, because members of outer With blocks are masked within the inner With blocks, you must provide a fully qualified object reference in an inner With block to any member of an object in an outer With block.